# Set default ringtone from private internal storage

Tags: android

Is it possible to set a default ringtone from private internal storage? I did set the default ringtone from private internal storage but it's not playing.

`file.getAbsolutePath = data/data/<package>/files/audio.mp3.`

Comment: If file.getAbsolutePath == /mnt/sdcard/ ringtone is playing. Any solution to hide the audio?

Comment: how can u say u set it when its not playing..

Comment: The name of the default ringtone was the name of audio I set. When I set it on external sdcard it's working.

Comment: try this `File yourFile = context.getFilesDir() + "/" + "audio.mp3";`

Comment: why the `==` are you trying to compare or soemthing??

Comment: already tried that Bishan.. not working.. `values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my testing (Android v.19), I can use `RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri()` to point to a ringtone on private, internal app storage without exception.

However, attempting to play this Ringtone simply plays the default sound. I'm betting the system application that plays Ringtones doesn't have access to your apps internal storage. Bad for this scenario, but good for security!